# Using traj package for clustering a set of rows

Tags: r, clustering, panel-data

I have a dataset that contains the observations of 30 people and each of them had done 20 experiments. But for simplicity let's assume I have a dataset like this:

```
ID     trial  response  reaction_time
"s1"     1        0         2.52
"s1"     2        1         3.12
"s1"     3        0         2.66
"s2"     1        1         1.42
"s2"     2        1         2.01
"s2"     3        0         1.20
```

I wanted to cluster subjects and because I have longitudinal trajectories, I thought of using traj package. But I think this package doesn't cluster a grouped data. Right?
What should I do to cluster my data based on subjects?

Comment: Good question that I think would get a better reach over at the sister site for stats.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.